# Count the number of values between value and value - x by variable

Tags: r, count, data.table

I have some data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(let=sample(sample(letters,2),5, replace=TRUE),
                  num=sample(1:10,5))
setDT(df1)
   let num
1:   j   7
2:   j   6
3:   g   1
4:   j   2
5:   j  10
```

and I would like to calculate the number of `num` that are less than or equal to `num` AND are greater than or equal to `num` - 4, by `let`. Using the data.table package would be preferable, but any solution using dplyr or base r would be fine too.
The output would look like this:

```
   let num countNumByLet
1:   j   7             2
2:   j   6             2
3:   g   1             1
4:   j   2             1
5:   j  10             3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there might be a better way to find n elements within 4 of each element in a vector, but below is what I can think of now:

```
df1<-
structure(list(let = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("g", 
"j"), class = "factor"), num = c(7, 6, 1, 2, 10), res = c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

setDT(df1)[,
.(countNumByLet=sapply(num,function(i)sum(num-i>=-4 & num <=i)),num=num),
by=let]
```

Answer (score 5):

This can also be solved using `non-equi` joins:

```
dt <- data.table(let = sample(sample(letters, n_let), n_let * n_per_grp, replace = T),
                 num = sample (20, n_let * n_per_grp, replace = T))

dt[, .(let, high = num + 4L, num)
   ][dt,
     on = .(let,
            num <= num,
            high >= num),
     .(countNumByLet = .N),
     by = .EACHI
     ][, high:= NULL][]

   let num countNumByLet
1:   j   7             2
2:   j   6             2
3:   g   1             1
4:   j   2             1
5:   j  10             3
```

For a dataset of 5, the method doesn't matter. But when scaling up, non-equi joins really help:

```
n_let <- 26
n_per_grp <- 1E1

dt <- data.table(let = sample(sample(letters, n_let), n_let * n_per_grp, replace = T),
                 num = sample (20, n_let * n_per_grp, replace = T))

# 260 observations; 26 groups
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression     min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>  <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 dt_sapply   2.41ms 2.67ms      364.    53.9KB
2 dt_non_equi 5.08ms 5.66ms      170.   223.7KB

#2,600 observations; 26 groups
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>  <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 dt_sapply   11.49ms 12.15ms      80.3    4.67MB
2 dt_non_equi  6.39ms  7.25ms     117.    398.8KB

#26,000 observations; 26 groups
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>  <bch:t> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 dt_sapply   404.1ms  404ms      2.47  403.46MB
2 dt_non_equi  24.2ms   25ms     39.8     2.09MB

#260,000 observations; 26 groups
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>  <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 dt_sapply     38.6s   38.6s    0.0259    38.8GB
2 dt_non_equi 524.2ms 524.2ms    1.91      19.1MB
```